# How to get started being a game designer

Tags: game-design

I was wondering how can I get started with game design & developement because Im not really good at any programming languages that used to make games

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Board games.  Or card games.  Or games that don't require computers at all.  In some ways, these are easier than computer games, because you don't have to spend time in the code if you want to change the rules, you just change them.  It's quick and easy to make a game using tokens or random craft stuff, and all you'd need is friends to play test the game.  Ideally, friends who like board games or whatnot (if you don't have any such friends, search for a local board game group or similar)

Answer (score 7):

### Mediums of Experimentation

Analogue mediums are great for getting started. Mediums such as card games, board game and pen-and-paper RPGs like Dungeons and Dragons require no computer skills, and teach you some universal truths to game design that carry across all mediums.

If you're gung-ho on being digital, try map making first. I'd suggest downloading the Unreal Development Kit, and getting used to it's mapping tool (UnrealEd).
Once you're comfortable with that, you can explore Kismet, which is a graphical, node-based programming tool for UnrealEd. You can program interactions without having to write a line of code.

Ultimately, though, knowledge of a simple scripting language such as Lua or Python will help in your designing a great deal, if for no other reasons than to help you structure your thoughts logically. They're easing enough to pick up, and a wealth of free resources exist to teach you.

---

### Progression of Design Expertise

When learning any art form (I consider Game Design to be an art), there are 4 stages of progress one should always undergo:

1. **Study and understand existing designs**. By expressing an interest in designing games, you've likely already done this for a while. Essentially, just look at existing games, new and retro, and try to divine the reasoning behind design choices.
2. **Recreate**. Take an existing game, and go through the process of designing it from scratch. Compare your final piece to the original product, and try to understand the reasons behind any disparities.
   This is important for developing an appreciation for more subtle aspects of design that often go unnoticed, yet can make the difference between a good game, and a great one.
3. **Modify**. Take an existing design, and modify it somehow (ideally to improve upon it, but keeping it at the same final quality is also okay).
   Design a Magic the Gathering card that is unique, yet balanced and powerful.
   Think of how you could improve tetris or space invaders.
   Modify De_dust2 to add a greater emphasis on teamwork.
   Whatever changes you make, the effect of said changes should be intentional.
4. **Original Design**. Using your experience modify games, make a new one from scratch.
   Write an original DnD campaign in a new setting.
   Create your own MTG-esque card game from scratch.
   Design a boardgame using an under-utilised theme with appropriate original mechanics.
   Make your own map for CSS or TF2 or UT2k4 from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Use in-game editors, mod tools, map editors, or for something really basic try something like [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com).

Answer (score 3):

Gamemaker is a very nice tool that doesn't require alot (if any) coding. It has a nice built in drop and drag system that will get you familiar with the basics; variables, functions etc. As you progress you can move over to inline coding at your own pace.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to learn a programming language; there are many great free tutorials on the web. You could also use something like Game Maker, as omgnoseat mentioned. You could also try to find a friend who'd be willing to help you code the games, and have you design graphics or something, and work as a small team..

You weren't very specific, about what parts of game development you need help with, and what you're good at.

Answer (score 0):

Try tool like Game Salad.

www.GameSalad.com

You need not have ANY programming knowledge, its so easy to use tool.

Hope you will find it useful.